Laravel Rebing Graphql Pagination Is 4-5X Slower Than Returning All Records
I have a graphql query using the Laravel GraphQL rebing library that is taking 50+ seconds right now locally.
When I run it with paginate it's 50+ seconds, but when I drop the paginate it returns all of the records in 15 seconds.
Because we have a ton of data, this is okay to return in ~ 15-20 seconds.
Why is the paginate adding so much time and how can we fix this?
Here is a video I sent to a colleague demonstrating the issue
https://www.loom.com/share/ffc1375e08e2445580593820ddbc8ef6?sid=2627d20b-8ac9-4508-865d-97b698b8f7f0
Even trying simplePaginate is slow
Here is the graphql query
query {
    playbook_campaigns(
        page: 1
        limit: 10
        sort: "-ltv"
        exclude_without_ltv: 0
        general_metric_filters: [
            { metric: "score", operator: ">", value1: 0, value2: null }
        ]
        client_ids: [3240, 1024]
        start_date: "2021-08-01"
        end_date: "2024-08-31"
        match_name_in_all_models: 1
        platform_ids: [1001, 1002]
    ) {
        data {
            id
            name
            client {
                id
                name
                logo
                industry {
                    id
                    name
                }
                business_type {
                    id
                    name
                }
                playbook_platform_match_rates {
                    platform {
                        id
                        name
                        slug
                    }
                    match_rate
                }
            }
            first_asset {
                domain_url
                url
                thumbnail
            }
            objective
            status
            spend
            roas
            revenue
            stop_rate
            retention_rate
            hold_rate
            score
            ctr
            cpc
            cpm
            cpa
            cvr
            clicks
            impressions
            conversions
            slug
            updated_at
            created_at
            last_refreshed
            ecomm_matched_metric {
                id
                ltv
                cac
            }
        }
        current_page
        from
        has_more_pages
        last_page
        per_page
        to
        total
    }
}

Here is the sql resulting from the graphql query using pagination. It takes 31 seconds for this sql query to complete in my sql gui client TablePlus.
    SELECT
        "playbook_campaigns".*
    FROM
        "playbook_campaigns"
        INNER JOIN "clients" ON "playbook_campaigns"."client_id" = "clients"."id"
        INNER JOIN "mv_playbook_total_campaign_metrics" AS "campaign_ex_spend" ON "campaign_ex_spend"."campaign_id" = "playbook_campaigns"."id"
            AND "campaign_ex_spend"."total_spend" >= 25
        INNER JOIN (( SELECT DISTINCT
                    (playbook_campaigns.id) AS campaign_id
                FROM
                    "playbook_campaigns"
                    INNER JOIN "clients" ON "playbook_campaigns"."client_id" = "clients"."id"
                    INNER JOIN "mv_playbook_meta_campaign_metrics_data_2years" ON "playbook_campaigns"."id" = "mv_playbook_meta_campaign_metrics_data_2years"."campaign_id"
                        AND "mv_playbook_meta_campaign_metrics_data_2years"."date" >= '2021-08-01'
                        AND "mv_playbook_meta_campaign_metrics_data_2years"."date" <= '2024-08-31'
                WHERE
                    "clients"."id" in(3240, 1024)
                    AND "playbook_campaigns"."platform_id" in(1001, 1002)
                    AND "playbook_campaigns"."tenant_id" = 1001
                    AND "playbook_campaigns"."deleted_at" IS NULL)
            UNION ALL ( SELECT DISTINCT
                    (playbook_campaigns.id) AS campaign_id
                FROM
                    "playbook_campaigns"
                    INNER JOIN "clients" ON "playbook_campaigns"."client_id" = "clients"."id"
                    INNER JOIN "mv_playbook_tiktok_campaign_metrics_data_2years" ON "playbook_campaigns"."id" = "mv_playbook_tiktok_campaign_metrics_data_2years"."campaign_id"
                        AND "mv_playbook_tiktok_campaign_metrics_data_2years"."date" >= '2021-08-01'
                        AND "mv_playbook_tiktok_campaign_metrics_data_2years"."date" <= '2024-08-31'
                WHERE
                    "clients"."id" in(3240, 1024)
                    AND "playbook_campaigns"."platform_id" in(1001, 1002)
                    AND "playbook_campaigns"."tenant_id" = 1001
                    AND "playbook_campaigns"."deleted_at" IS NULL)) AS "joining_filter_by_date" ON "playbook_campaigns"."id" = "joining_filter_by_date"."campaign_id"
            INNER JOIN ((
                    SELECT
                        playbook_campaigns.id AS campaign_id, ANY_VALUE(playbook_campaigns_ecomm_ltv.ltv) AS total_filtered_ltv
                    FROM
                        "playbook_campaigns"
                        INNER JOIN "clients" ON "playbook_campaigns"."client_id" = "clients"."id"
                        INNER JOIN "mv_playbook_meta_campaign_metrics_data_2years" ON "playbook_campaigns"."id" = "mv_playbook_meta_campaign_metrics_data_2years"."campaign_id"
                            AND "mv_playbook_meta_campaign_metrics_data_2years"."date" >= '2021-08-01'
                            AND "mv_playbook_meta_campaign_metrics_data_2years"."date" <= '2024-08-31'
                    LEFT JOIN "playbook_ecomm_matched_metrics" AS "playbook_campaigns_ecomm_ltv" ON "playbook_campaigns_ecomm_ltv"."campaign_id" = "playbook_campaigns"."id"
                WHERE
                    "clients"."id" in(3240, 1024)
                    AND "playbook_campaigns"."platform_id" in(1001, 1002)
                    AND "playbook_campaigns"."tenant_id" = 1001
                    AND "playbook_campaigns"."deleted_at" IS NULL
                GROUP BY
                    "playbook_campaigns"."id")
            UNION ALL (
                SELECT
                    playbook_campaigns.id AS campaign_id,
                    ANY_VALUE(playbook_campaigns_ecomm_ltv.ltv) AS total_filtered_ltv
                FROM
                    "playbook_campaigns"
                    INNER JOIN "clients" ON "playbook_campaigns"."client_id" = "clients"."id"
                    INNER JOIN "mv_playbook_tiktok_campaign_metrics_data_2years" ON "playbook_campaigns"."id" = "mv_playbook_tiktok_campaign_metrics_data_2years"."campaign_id"
                        AND "mv_playbook_tiktok_campaign_metrics_data_2years"."date" >= '2021-08-01'
                        AND "mv_playbook_tiktok_campaign_metrics_data_2years"."date" <= '2024-08-31'
                LEFT JOIN "playbook_ecomm_matched_metrics" AS "playbook_campaigns_ecomm_ltv" ON "playbook_campaigns_ecomm_ltv"."campaign_id" = "playbook_campaigns"."id"
            WHERE
                "clients"."id" in(3240, 1024)
                AND "playbook_campaigns"."platform_id" in(1001, 1002)
                AND "playbook_campaigns"."tenant_id" = 1001
                AND "playbook_campaigns"."deleted_at" IS NULL
            GROUP BY
                "playbook_campaigns"."id")) AS "total_from_filter_metrics" ON "playbook_campaigns"."id" = "total_from_filter_metrics"."campaign_id"
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT
                scores.campaign_id AS campaign_id,
                percentile_cont(0.5::double precision)
                WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY (scores.score::double precision)) AS total_filtered_score
            FROM
                "playbook_campaigns"
                INNER JOIN "clients" ON "playbook_campaigns"."client_id" = "clients"."id"
                INNER JOIN "mv_playbook_last_2year_ad_scores" AS "scores" ON "playbook_campaigns"."id" = "scores"."campaign_id"
            WHERE
                "clients"."id" in(3240, 1024)
                AND "playbook_campaigns"."platform_id" in(1001, 1002)
                AND "scores"."platform_id" in(1001, 1002)
                AND "scores"."date" >= '2021-08-01'
                AND "scores"."date" <= '2024-08-31'
                AND "playbook_campaigns"."tenant_id" = 1001
                AND "playbook_campaigns"."deleted_at" IS NULL GROUP BY
                    "scores"."campaign_id") AS "joining_total_score" ON "playbook_campaigns"."id" = "joining_total_score"."campaign_id"
            WHERE
                "clients"."id" in(3240, 1024)
                AND "playbook_campaigns"."platform_id" in(1001, 1002)
                AND "joining_total_score"."total_filtered_score" > 0
                AND "playbook_campaigns"."tenant_id" = 1001
                AND "playbook_campaigns"."deleted_at" IS NULL
            ORDER BY
                total_from_filter_metrics.total_filtered_ltv DESC NULLS LAST LIMIT 10

After running explain (analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) on the query, here is a link to a doc containing the query plan (there were too many characters to post it in the stackoverflow post)
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1hClUdfR4-IIXHumsUi9vbbl8PZBpUBSFdigwM0EXTI4/edit?usp=sharing
I put the query plan in pgexplain.dev and it showed the bottleneck was a group aggregate

Using XDebug I stepped into the paginate function and I timed the execution of finding the paginated total (which takes 36 seconds)
[

Commenting out certain where statements appears to make the query run a lot faster. I have seen that with commenting out the AND "joining_total_score"."total_filtered_score" > 0

Could you please share the SQL statement, the result from explain (analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) for this statement and the ddl for all tables and indexes involved? All in plain text. We can now not even guess what goes wrong

@FrankHeikens I added the sql query, query plan, and screenshot from pgexplain using the query plan

To be honest, to me it looks like the query is the problem. You're collecting data from playbook_campaigns 6 times, in such a way that it can't be optimized by the query planner. I would rewrite the query and try again. One of the few things you can do, is increase work_mem to avoid the sorting on disk. But that won't make a huge difference, maybe a few seconds.

@FrankHeikens the problem is the query is being generated from the ORM (Laravel Framework) and we need to join playbook campaigns several times in order to get all the data needed in this one query

I noticed, so I wish you good luck with that. In my not so humble opinion an ORM is good for simple SQL (that any developer could produce) and usually fails miserably on complex SQL. You just proved it again.

@FrankHeikens you are so so right haha. It's slower and does a lot more work than needed
